# How can I properly use related_name in django models to get back the class name?

Tags: python, django

I have an application called "school" inside one of my django projects.

**Below is the code of models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True)

class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name='classes',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**And now, views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def test(request):
    obj2 = Student.objects.get(name='john')
    return render(request,'test/list.html', {'obj2':obj2} )
```

**And finally, my template looks like this:**

```
{% block content %}
<h2>
{{ obj2.classes }}
</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

In my template, I am using obj2.classes (i.e., responseobject.related_name). I want it to print the class name.
However when I access the site at http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/ ,
it gives me this output:

```
shop.Class.None
```

How will I get the output as only "Class", that is the class name?

Comment: `obj2.classes` would be a RelatedManager, which can provide the individual related "Class" instances. So in your template, you should loop over it with something like `{% for cls in obj2.classes.all 5 %} {{ cls }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: @Håken Lid, I don't think so. First of all, in my example, obj2 contains only one instance as I have used obj2= Student.objects.get(name= 'john').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `obj2._meta.get_field('classes').related_model.__name__` do the job? This will work on your view only, not on the template.

```
def test(request):
    obj2 = Student.objects.get(name='john')
    classes_name = obj2._meta.get_field('classes').related_model.__name__
    return render(request, 'test/list.html',
                  {'obj2':obj2, 'classes_name': classes_name})
```

Using this method, you avoid to use `obj2.classes`, which hits the database to retrieve the object.

You can also get the verbose_name with `obj2._meta.get_field('classes').related_model._meta.verbose_name`.